# What is the current state of wheel build reproducibility in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, python-wheel

I know there has been effort around making the wheel files reproducible when building the same python package twice, per release notes for 0.27.0 of wheel: https://wheel.readthedocs.io/en/stable/news.html

By "reproducible" I mean: "wheel files hash to the same hash each time built".

Reproducibility when compiling on the same machine with the same code / resources would be a good start --- across different machines with same code / resources would be even better.

I've been trying to determine if there is similar progress on reproducible builds on Windows, and if not, what "hacks" can I do to make that happen? (for example, overriding an environment variable)

The hack of last resort is spinning up a docker container just to compile my wheel file.  If I have to, I will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  On Windows 10, I included a line like this in my setup.py:

```
os.environ["SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH"] = "315532800"
```